# Problem in accessing json type data in python

Tags: python, json

```
'{"country1":"japan1", "country2":"japan2", "language": "\\nabc::{\\n  first_language:hindi,\\n  second_language:\\"jui-juki-oiu.ghj\\",\\n  third_language:\\"567987\\",\\n  input_encoding:\\"UTF-8\\",\\n  output_encoding:\\"IBM768\\",\\n  audit_info:{\\n    created_by:someone,\\n    creation_date:2017-09-24T15:19:20.632-00:00\\n  },\\n}"}'
```

I am fetching this data from some api. I am not able to access second_language data.
How can i access this data in python.

Comment: What is `\\nabc::` in your json?
If I parse your string with `json` I get:

`{'country1': 'japan1',
 'country2': 'japan2',
 'language': '\nabc::{\n  first_language:hindi,\n  second_language:"jui-juki-oiu.ghj",\n  third_language:"567987",\n  input_encoding:"UTF-8",\n  output_encoding:"IBM768",\n  audit_info:{\n    created_by:someone,\n    creation_date:2017-09-24T15:19:20.632-00:00\n  },\n}'}`
which is probably not what you want

Comment: Are you able to access second_language by some method?

Comment: Well in this json, the value corresponding to the key `language` is a giant string `\nabc::{\n first_language:hindi,\n second_language:"jui-juki-oiu.ghj",\n third_language:"567987",\n input_encoding:"UTF-8",\n output_encoding:"IBM768",\n audit_info:{\n created_by:someone,\n creation_date:2017-09-24T15:19:20.632-00:00\n `. So to get `second_language` you would have to build a regex such as `.*second_language:"([^\"]+)".*` and then extract the second language, but your main problem is that your json is malformed

Comment: This is the data i am getting from the api. Isn't that something related to json_class?

Comment: The format is hard to parse: it is not valid json, nor direct Python representation. IMHO, you should fix the way you get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If really you want to parse this ill-formed json, you'll need regular expression:

```
import json
import re
data = json.loads(s)
weird_string = data['language'].replace('\n', ' ')
reg = re.compile('.*second_language:\\"([^#]+?)".*')
matcher = reg.match(weird_string)
second_language = matcher.group(1)
```

but the right way to go would be to fix the way you get this json...